# natural staining on wood from human skin

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have a question about the dark staining that occurs on my wooden spectacle frames where they rub constantly with my skin around the ears and nose. Can anyone tell me what is causing this? And could it be reproduced artificially?

I think you can see what I'm talking about in the photo. (Excuse poor image quality).

I make the glasses, and one of the difficulties is finding a good way to stain them - dark frames suite many people best but the woods from around here are mostly light. If I could only make them go dark like they do from rubbing with skin. But all over. That would be perfect. Anyone think it could be done?

[image: dark stains on wooden spec' frames]

Comment: This darkening is most likely caused by skin oil. A polish of oil (just for trial even olive oil) may make the wood appear darker.

Comment: I wanted to comment as above. Also wetting should do the same.

Comment: Wetting would darken the wood, but not nearly as much as this.

Comment: Application of oil (olive oil, linseed oil) does darken the wood, but not nearly this much. I have applied something like 17 coats of linseed oil to some oak wood, with nothing like this much darkening.